# MYSQL doesn't start up in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

i'm a newbie,i have  installed XAMPP on my computer (vista) but  MYSQL doesn't start up , I  see the message ''TERMINATING WORKER TREAD 1" How can i fix this, please be specific because i don't know anything about this , thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to several reasons. Most likely some other application listens to the MySQL TCP-Port, the [port 3306](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/security-guidelines.html).

On which operation system does MySQL run?

Comment: On VISTA or do you mean something else? I dont know how to check what application is using this portal and how to solve it if this is the problem, MYSQL is using port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: i just solved this on my system myself; you very well may have downloaded multiple copies of mysql that start when you boot your system so port 3306 is occupied. On mac systems you can open the activity monitor and simply search 'mysql'. After that click the stop button. Do the same on windows in the activity monitor (I'm assuming) hope it helps